# Macro that does nothing (PHP source code)

Tags: php, c

While looking through the PHP source code, I found this macro :

```
#define YYFILL(n) do {} while (0)
```

To me, it looks like this does nothing. However, YYFILL(n) is being called multiple times in the source code. eg:

```
if((YYLIMIT - YYCURSOR) < 7) YYFILL(7)
```

What is the purpose of this macro?

location of this function in the PHP source code for reference: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.4/ext/standard/var_unserializer.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`YYFILL` is a macro used by [`re2c`](http://re2c.org), which is a program that accepts a regular expression and produces C/C++ source code to parse it. PHP uses re2c in various locations where a parser is needed.

If `YYFILL` does nothing, then the parser code cannot refill its input buffer. This probably implies that the original input buffer is expected to be complete and valid. (Refilling the input buffer would be something that you would do if you were, say, reading contents from a file.)

The `do {} while (0)` form is there to ensure that `YYFILL` is followed by a semicolon and does not parse into a weird construct if it's used in a weird sequence of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I use such things as placeholders. Say, in your example, you haven't decided what to do when cursor gets above the vertical limit. At the same time, you want to leave a note at this place, something like a todo in the comment.

Comment: This code isn't unfinished, though - this macro is being used as an intentional "do nothing", as explained by zneak. Also, for what it's worth: the term "cursor" here has nothing to do with a cursor on screen.